# How to change text in span using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm pretty new to Ajax and JQuery. I'm trying to change the value of a span when I type text in an input box but nothing is working(i.e the value in the span is not changing). After some research around StackOverflow, I found out that I should either use the `text()` or `html()` of JQuery to change the value but it still does not change. I'm not sure where I went wrong. Below is my code:

**Html of Input Box:**

```
<input class="amnt" id ="Red:XL:50:24.55" type="text">
<span id="50-Red-24.55">0(This text is not changing)</span>
```

**Here's my JQuery. It first performs an Ajax(I omitted this part) and then after Ajax success, it should change the value of my span:**

```
$( ".amnt" ).keyup(function() {
    var split = this.id.split(":");
    var color = split[0];
    var size = split[1];
    var ID = split[2];
    var price = split[3];

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to getData.php
        success: function(response){                  

            $("#"+ID+"-"+color+"-"+price).text(price);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

I also tried `$("#"+ID+"-"+color+"-"+price).html(price);` instead of `$("#"+ID+"-"+color+"-"+price).text(price);` but nothig changes on `keyup`.
Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the AJAX call is successful and that all the variables are what you expect them to be?

Comment: The issue is that periods in the selector is assumed to be classes

Comment: @Shomz Yes the ajax call is successful, otherwise I would have gotten the alert(thrownError). I also tested the success with another alert and it worked. It's just the span that's not changing for some reason.

Comment: @adeneo, you should write that as an answer, though note that the periods are legit parts of an ID, but jQuery is not the smartest to handle it.

Comment: @Shomz - true, periods are valid, but must be escaped, and preferably one would just avoid special characters and make life easier.

Comment: @adeneo I get what you mean. But the period is important is this case as it's part of the price. How would I go about to escape it and take it into consideration with the id?

Comment: You could try `price.replace('.','\\.')`

Comment: @adeneo, please write an answer so we can close this.

Comment: @adeneo Excellent. This worked perfect. Please make it into an answer so others could benefit. And explain why this works and how the Javascript gets "confused" as well hehe :-) Thanks

Comment: Nah, there's already good answers, and using an identifier that just indentifies the element, nothing more, and then using data attributes to filter on data etc, seems like a much better idea ?

Comment: But you are the only one who pin-pointed the problem and did not take the other path. **I insist!** :) (if you give me your login credentials, I'll write it)

Comment: @adeneo It is indeed a much better way of doing things to use data attributes. It's a bit hard for beginners to figure that out. But your answer is what matters for the question. Up to you if you want to put it or not :-)

Comment: @user3029017 has already posted an answer showing how to *"escape"* string for jQuery selectors

Comment: @nTuply, since it's the part of the price, you can replace that comma with pretty much any other legal ID character (except for a number, of course) and stay away from jQuery's problems.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Shomz

Comment: for your reference ,
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem (credits to @adeneo):

In the interpolated selector string, jQuery sees periods (which are perfectly fine ID characters) as class names, so something like `"#my.cool.id"` would actually select this element:

```
<div id="my" class="cool id"></div>
```

and not this one:

```
<div id="my.cool.id"></div>
```

### The solution:

To avoid that issue, simply escape or replace the period in your price part of the ID with any legal ID character that's not a number or a period or a colon (since you're usign it for splitting), for example, `24X55`, `24|55`, etc. will all work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of concatenating different items to create the Id string, It would be better and clean, if you use relative selectors in your code.

Add a css class to your message span and wrap this in a container div. Also instead of keeping your data inside the Id value, you may keep those in HTML 5 data attributes.

```
<div class="amtContainer">
  <input class="amnt" data-size="XL" data-price="24.55" type="text">
  <span class="amtMsg">0(This text is not changing)</span>
</div>
```

And in your script, use the `closest()` method to get a reference to the outer container div, and then use `find()` method to get to the message span.

```
$( ".amnt" ).keyup(function() {
    var _this= $(this);
    var val=_this.val();

    var price=_this.data("price");

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to getData.php
        success: function(response){                  

           _this.closest(".amtContainer").find(".amtMsg").text(price);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Rewriting a piece of code is not equal to solving a problem with that code. @adeneo gave the correct answer.

Comment: I like how you showed me the use of `data-price`, etc for a clean approach to my problem. I'll definitely use that as future reference but for now there's way to much code to edit. Why wouldn't my way work?

Comment: I personally do not prefer to add more fixes to a complicated and unreadable solution than switching to a more clean and readable solution. Future code readability ( for you and your peers) is very important. JS is not a statically typed language and i am way too worried about keeping the code clean. There is no pressure. Use/write code the way you feel comfortable. This was my humble suggestion. Feel free to ignore it :)

Comment: Yeah, but we're still on SO, not CodeReview. :) Just one character is the issue here - jQuery has issues with dots in the IDs, as @adeneo explained in the comments.

Comment: I'm new and didn't know of that way you mentioned. It's clean and perfect for my future use(which I will actually adopt). Thanks for that. :-) However, my question is just different.

Answer (score 2):

First create the **id** concatenating the variables. Then replace `.` with `\\.` and use the modified id to select the span element. Then use `.html()` to change text in the span.

You can use this function to escape css selector characters from your id string

```
function jq( myid ) {

    return myid.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,)/g, "\\$1" );

}
```

Reference: 
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/